# Ionic Select not working on windows 10 Tab

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, windows-10-universal

I understand Ionic does not officially support windows 10 yet, but unfortunately I need whatever framework I choose to use to work on Windows as well as iOS and Android, and I Love the look of Ionic, and would really like to use it.

Anyway, a simple app seems to launch OK, but just a couple of problems, one being the **Select** widget, i.e. drop-down combo box, do not seem to work.

Has anyone happened to have found a fix for this?

Thanks in advance for any info!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have found any solution to your problem, but @PerfectionCSGO's solution works great (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4803)

```
angular.module('starter').directive('select', selectDirective);
selectDirective.$inject = [];
function selectDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        link: function (scope, element) {
            if (ionic.Platform && ionic.Platform.isWindowsPhone()) {
                element.attr('data-tap-disabled', 'true');
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I still have an issue with the highlighted option in the list, which is not on the selected option, so the selected option appears in white in the list bug the blue background is on another option.